# Android: tablerow disappears?

Tags: android, layout

I have a `<TableLayout>` with two `<TableRow>`s. The first row contains two buttons (this works fine), and the second row contains a `<FrameLayout>` that contains an `<ImageView>`. My problem is, the second `TableRow` (and `FrameLayout`) do not appear until I load an image into the `ImageView`. I want the `FrameLayout` to be visible (with its background color) at all times.

I have used `android:layout_width="match_parent"` and `android:layout_height="match_parent"` in the `<ImageView>` and `<FrameLayout>`, but it does not seem to help.

Here is the layout xml:

```
<TableLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingTop="5dp"
    android:stretchColumns="1">
    <TableRow>
        <Button
            android:id="@+id/buttonLoadPhoto"
            android:text="Load..."
            android:textSize="20sp"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1" />
        <Button
            android:id="@+id/buttonPrintPhoto"
            android:text="Print..."
            android:textSize="20sp"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1" />
    </TableRow>
    <TableRow
        android:background="#FF4422">
        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@+id/frameLayoutPhoto"
            xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:background="#303030">
            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/imageViewPhoto"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:scaleType="matrix">
            </ImageView>
        </FrameLayout>
    </TableRow>
</TableLayout>
```

Note 1: I have included a background color for the offending `<TableRow>` just so I could narrow down the problem to the `TableRow` and not the `ImageView` (the `TableRow`'s background color does not show up).

Note 2: This is the layout for an `Activity` that is loaded into a `<TabHost>`'s `<FrameLayout>`, in case that matters.

Note 3: I am targeting Android 2.2, and I am using a Xoom to test.

Essentially, I want the `<FrameLayout>` to take up the remaining space in the tab. Is there an alternative way to do this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found an alternative solution using `<LinearLayout>`s instead:

```
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:paddingTop="5dp">
    <LinearLayout
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
        <Button
            android:id="@+id/buttonLoadPhoto"
            android:text="Load..."
            android:textSize="20sp"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1" />
        <Button
            android:id="@+id/buttonPrintPhoto"
            android:text="Print..."
            android:textSize="20sp"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1" />
    </LinearLayout>
    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/frameLayoutPhoto"
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="#303030">
        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageViewPhoto"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:scaleType="matrix">
        </ImageView>
    </FrameLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

The [documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TableRow.html) states that layout_height should be WRAP_CONTENT and width should be MATCH_PARENT, and that you do not need to specify these since it will enforce it anyway. I'm not sure if you added those in as you were trying to debug it or not.

**Edit** (This line is incorrect, but remains here as it is mentioned in the comments):You can also try setting a height for the TableRow, since none is provided and the content inside of it does not have a height until an image is there.

Comment: I haven't added them in, because it said it was not necessary. I just tried adding `android:layout_height="200dp"` to the second `<TableRow>` but it did not do anything.

Comment: your frame layout is a child of TableRow, and you did set the width and height in the code you provided above, which doesn't have to be there.

Comment: Oh, the documentation is talking about the children of TableRow, I see. Removing them made no difference

Comment: Reading further, it appears the last line of my answer is incorrect, as you found, I dont think it's possible to set the height directly in the TableRow.

Comment: Just wondering, is it necessary to use a table layout instead of something like a LinearLayout?

Comment: I just added this to the question: Essentially, I want the `<FrameLayout>` to take up the remaining space in the tab. Is there an alternative way to do this?